What is the correct way of handling deeply nested jsons with Rsuite's Tree component?
I have a customized Tree Component of Rsuite component library, where my intention is to add new child for any node. I have been successfull in doing that, but it seems the react component cannot handle a deeply nested/large json data as it grows.
Rsuite: Tree
kindly suggest a way to solve this rendering issue for large jsons.
I have explored two options:

Normal Rendering the Tree component (without virtualized=true) -> this causes a UI freeze.
Virtualized rendering (with prop virtualized=true) -> this causes the following error:

Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My code for the component is given below:
const sample = [
    {
        label: 'Node 1',
        value: '1',
        path: [0],
        children: [
            {
                label: 'Node 1-1',
                value: '1-1',
                path: [0, 0],
                children: [
                    {
                        label: 'Node 1-1-1',
                        value: '1-1-1',
                        path: [0, 0, 0],
                        children: [
                            {
                                label: "Node 1-1-1-1",
                                value: "1-1-1-1",
                                path: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Node 2',
        value: '2',
        path: [1],
        children: [
            {
                label: 'Node 2-1',
                value: '2-1',
                path: [1, 0]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Node 3',
        value: '3',
        path: [2]
    }
];

function TreeNode({ children, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <div {...rest} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', gap: 4 }}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

function customRenderTreeNode(treeNode, isAddingChild, setIsAddingChild) {
    return (
        <TreeNode>
            {treeNode.label}
            <Button
                onClick={() => setIsAddingChild(!isAddingChild)} color="green" appearance="ghost" size="xs" >
                + Child
            </Button>
            <Button color="red" appearance="ghost" size="xs" >- Delete</Button>
        </TreeNode>
    )
}

function RsuiteTreeViewer() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(sample);
    const [isAddingChild, setIsAddingChild] = useState(false);
    const [selectedNode, setSelectedNode] = useState(null);
    const [newNodeName, setNewNodeName] = useState('');
    const listRef = useRef();

    function addChild(data, path, newNode) {
        if (!data || !Array.isArray(data))
            return;

        if (data.length === 0) {
            data.push(newNode);
            return data;
        }

        let t = data;

        for (let i = 0; i <= path.length; i++) {
            if (!t.children)
                t.children = [];

            if (i === path.length) {
                t.children.push(newNode);
                break;
            }
            else if (!Array.isArray(t)) {
                t = t.children[path[i]];
            }
            else {
                t = t[path[i]];
            }
        }
    }

    function handleAddChild(event) {
        setIsAddingChild(!isAddingChild);
        console.debug(selectedNode);

        const randomId = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);

        const newChild = {
            id: randomId,
            refKey: `String_${randomId}`,
            path: [...selectedNode.path, (selectedNode.children ? selectedNode.children.length : 0)],
            label: newNodeName
        }
        console.debug(newChild);
        addChild(data, selectedNode.path, newChild);
        const clone = structuredClone(data);
        setData(clone);

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Tree
                defaultExpandAll
                virtualized
                scrollShadow
                data={data}
                onSelect={(activeNode) => setSelectedNode(activeNode)}
                renderTreeNode={
                    (treeNode) => customRenderTreeNode(treeNode, isAddingChild, setIsAddingChild)}
            />
            {
                isAddingChild &&
                <Stack spacing={10} direction="column" alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent="flex-start">
                    <Text weight="medium" size="md">New Node Name</Text>
                    <Input value={newNodeName} onChange={setNewNodeName} />
                    <Button onClick={handleAddChild} color="green" appearance="primary">Add</Button>
                </Stack>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

